# What is the proper name for this rubber edging trim for fibreglass?

Tags: trim, fiberglass, rubber

I have a fibreglass seat pan, and it was damaged.  What's the correct name for the edging stuff?   I hope that I can find something large enough to cover the road-rash.

[image]

[image]

There's a springy steel-toothed core, and it slips over the raw edge of a fibreglass shape to protect it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This happens to be a seat from a recumbent bicycle, but the question is generic.  This kind of bike seat is uncommon so not really suitable for bicycles.SE, and teh DIYers of the world are more likely to know the right words.

Comment: Not sure why this is garnering close votes, we get plenty of "identify this part" questions. If it happened to be a trim strip for a fiberglass shower surround instead of fiberglass bike seat, there wouldn't be any question at all.

Comment: Agree with @FreeMan.  Can see that being used for quite a few things besides a bike seat.  Have a table that has something similar along the bottom edge.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about DIY Home Improvement. If someone wants to ask a similar question about some sort of similar edging used somewhere in a home then they're free to do so...

Comment: @brhans Fair observation, which is why I framed it as an ***identification*** question rather than a "bike repair"  The latter I can do perfectly well.   That "DIY" is not directly interchangeable with "Home Improvement" was covered in https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266/diy-vs-home-improvement

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're referring to in that meta link, but the big banner at the top of the page literally reads "Home Improvement". Don't be mislead by the page URL - the fact that you want to Do **It** Yourself doesn't necessarily make **It** on-topic here.. https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

So possible search terms are:

edging, protective edging or edge protector or edge protector strip or U channel ...

Often used with door & protector

Searching on Bay of Fleas gives many results with and without the internal spring.

Answer (score 2):

In Norway, it goes under the name of Volvolist, named after a certain car brand.

The proper name for it is edge protection, and vendors such as RS Online have multiple hits when you search for edge protection.